# trace_console definition in Linux kernel v3.5 not found

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In Linux kernel version **3.5**, in file **kernel/printk.c** there is a function call

`trace_console(text, 0, len, len);` @line 1219

I am not able to find the definition of this function. I greped the complete kernel for it and also tried it with cscope and ctags, but still I was not able to find the definition for it. Is there any concept I am missing for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it is hidden inside a macro (or rather, TWO macros, one for tracing enabled, one for when it's turned off) in include/linux/tracepoints.h:

[__DECLARE_TRACE](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.5/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L146) definition when tracing is enabled.

[__DECLARE_TRACE](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.5/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L206) definition when tracing is disabled.

Tracing is enabled/disabled with the CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS in your .config

The actual trace_console is generated in include/trace/events/printk.h:
[TRACE_EVENT_CONDITION](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.5/include/trace/events/printk.h#L9)